# MySQL query strange behaviour for a column containing NULL values

Tags: mysql

My query is

```
SELECT partnumber, side FROM crpt_admin_orders_partnumbers
WHERE order_id = 198 AND side != 'B'
```

so in side column expected value is `NULL, 'A', 'B'`. I need to get all `Null` and `'A'` records, but this query is not returning any results.

if I run

```
SELECT partnumber, side FROM crpt_admin_orders_partnumbers
WHERE order_id = 198 AND side is NULL
```

then it returns me 2 records.

What is the possible cause for this not working. And what is the solutions. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to test for NULL specifically, you can't use mathematical operators.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html

> The NULL value can be surprising until you get used to it. Conceptually, NULL means “a missing unknown value” and it is treated somewhat differently from other values.

Comment: Right now, i have used `(side = 'A' or side is NULL)` in where condition and it is working